# Why doesn't this algorithm for reversing a LinkedList in java fit θ(N)?

Tags: java, linked-list

A question on an assignment that I have is to write an algorithm to reverse a LinkedList producing a new list in θ(N) time.

The code I have come up with does not meet the time requirements and I cannot work out why.

```
public Node reverse() {

    if (this == Node.NIL) {
        return Node.NIL;
    }

    if (this.getNext() == Node.NIL) {
        return new Node(this.getItem(), this.getNext());
    }

    Node curNode = new Node(this.getItem(), this.getNext());
    Node front = curNode;

    Node nextNode = null;
    Node prevNode = null;

    while (curNode.getNext() != Node.NIL) {
        nextNode = new Node(curNode.next.item, curNode.next.next);
        curNode.next = prevNode;
        prevNode = curNode;
        curNode = nextNode;
    }

    curNode.next = prevNode;
    front.setNext(Node.NIL);
    return curNode;
}
```

There is a node called NIL which should be referred to as Node.NIL which is always the first node created in the provided lists to reverse, so if Node.NIL is the next node you will be at the end of the list.

Each node has 2 attributes, "next" and "item" - "next" being the next node in the list, and "item" being the data it carries which is an Object in this case.

This is the test that is being used (NCASES = 20):

```
@Test
public void testReverseTiming() {
    int i;
    long diff = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < NCASES - 1; i++) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        Node result = nodes2[i].reverse();
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        diff = end - start;
        if (diff/1000000 > 250) {
            i++;
            break;
        }
    }
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    Node result = nodes2[i].reverse();
    long end = System.nanoTime();
    long diff2 = end - start;
    double ratio = (double) diff2 / (double) diff;
    assertTrue("reverse should scale linearly with list size", ratio > 1.2);
    assertTrue("reverse should scale linearly with list size", ratio < 2.5);
}
```

The ratio that my code produces ranges from 25 to 35 whereas it needs to be between 1.2 and 2.5.

Comment: It appears to be O(n). Unless you do something insanely inefficient, I'd expect reversing to always be O(n).

Comment: @Carcigenicate Please see my edits on the question.

Comment: I don't really get what you're doing in the test. And I would expect the while loop in `reverse` to run as many times as there are elements in the list (assuming the algorithm is correct. I'm too tired to judge that by looking at it right now.), meaning it's O(n). I've never heard of actually timing the algorithm to verify complexity. There's potentially too much going on for it to be exact.

Comment: @Carcigenicate My professor wrote the test, he's timing how long it takes to reverse X nodes, then timing how long it takes to reverse 10X nodes and checking the time scales linearly; it seems this is a very inaccurate way of doing things.

Answer (score 3):

Since your code seems to iterate through the list only once, it seems to be, infact, O(n).

However, you allocate objects inside your look (`new Node()`), so the actual performance will depend on memory allocation (which will include OS-calls for large datasets) and garbage collection. Both of which takes an undetermined amount of time. This means that even if the algorithm (in theory) is O(n), the measured runtimes will depend on other factors than n.

You should try to rewrite your algorithm to change the links of existing nodes instead of creating new nodes. (I assume the assignment is to reverse the existing list in place, not create a reversed copy of the list)

Comment: What you say about timings makes a lot of sense and so I guess that is the issue. Unfortunately I do have to return a new list, not reverse the existing list in place.